# Is there another script for this query in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

is there another script for this query in DAX? an entry where there is no redundancy, notably for the Fac and the Fic which have the same code to check them.

```
del = COUNTX(      
    FILTER('dashboard',('dashboard'[sector]="Fic" && dashboard[code]="DEA") 
         + ('dashboard'[sector]="Fic" &&     dashboard[code]="RES")+ 
('dashboard'[sector]="Fic" &&     dashboard[code]="RES_AR")+ 
('dashboard'[sector]="Fic" &&     dashboard[code]="RES_CT")
    ||,('dashboard'[sector]="Fac" && dashboard[code]="DEA")+     
('dashboard'[sector]="Fac" && dashboard[code]="RES")+     
('dashboard'[sector]="Fac" && dashboard[code]="RES_AR")+     
('dashboard'[sector]="Fac" && dashboard[code]="RES_CT")          
,dashboard[sector])
```

I think there is a lot of improvement in this writing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Del =
VAR SectorCodeFilter =
    FILTER (
        ALL ( dashboard[sector], dashboard[code] ),
        ( dashboard[sector], dashboard[code] )
            IN {
            ( "Fic", "DEA" ),
            ( "Fic", "RES" ),
            ( "Fic", "RES_AR" ),
            ( "Fic", "RES_CT" ),
            ( "Fac", "DEA" ),
            ( "Fac", "RES" ),
            ( "Fac", "RES_AR" ),
            ( "Fac", "RES_CT" )
        }
    )
VAR Result =
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( dashboard ),
        KEEPFILTERS ( SectorCodeFilter )
    )
RETURN
    Result
```